# what comes before "for i in range (...)"

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I have a simple question, looking at the following code:

```
 letters = [hand[i]][:1] for i in range(5)]
```

What does the argument before 'for I in range(5)' do?? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: your code seems incorrect because of the additional `]` you have after `hand[i]`

Comment: Does - [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) - answer your question? ... [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings)

Comment: Makes so much sense, thanks! Andyes noted on the extra ] - I saw that afterwards

Answer (score 4):

A simple list comprehension has three parts:

```
my_list = [A for B in C]
```

This translates exactly into:

```
my_list = []
for B in C:
    my_list.append(A)
```

So the part before `for` determines what goes into the list you're creating.

---

In your case, you could also write it like this:

```
letters = []
for i in range(i):
    letters.append(hand[i][:1]])
```

Comment: ... hand[i] is the *ith* item in hand ... [1:] is a slice which *excludes* the first item of hand[i].

Comment: he has `[:1]` so he only takes a slice of one element, the element `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

The upper piece of code is called list comprehension:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

So the upper code could be explicitly written out as:

```py
hand # some data. From your code it should be a nested list, eq: hand = [ [...],[...],... ]
letters = []
for i in range(5): # iterates trough 0-4
    element = hand[i][:1] 
    letters.append(element)
```

So this is just a very short way of constructing a list. You read it out lout like so:
**For every `i` from `range(5)` take element(s) `hand[i][:1]` and assign it to a new list `letters`.**

If your question is about the part `hand[i][:1]`, then this is a slice from a nested list. For example:

```py
hand = [
  [0,1,2,3],
  [4,5,6,7],
  ...
]

hand[0] == [0,1,2,3]
hand[0][:1] == [0]
hand[1][:1] == [4] # mind it is a slice, so you are left with a list!!
```